# Creating a dataframe in Python

Tags: python

Not sure how to correctly phrase this, but here goes:

What's the easiest way to create a one-column dataframe in Python that holds ones and zeros, and the length is determined by some input?

For example, say that I have a sample size of 1000, of which a 100 successes (ones). The amount of zeros would then be the sample size (i.e., 1000) minus successes. So the output would be a df with a length of 1000, of which a 100 rows contain a one and 900 a zero.

Comment: Is it in order or random?

Comment: No requirements for that – could be both.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, a simple `list` would do the trick. Otherwise, you can use `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame`/`pandas.Series` (more table-like).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input_length = 1000

# List approach:
my_list = [0 for i in range(input_length)]
# Numpy array:
my_array = np.zeros(input length)
# With Pandas:
my_table = pd.Series(0, index=range(input_length))
```

All these create a vector of zeroes, then you assign the successes (ones) as you please. If these were to follow some known distribution, numpy also has methods to generate random vectors that follow them ([see here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.random.html)).

If you're really looking for the pandas approach, it can also be combined with the previous ones. This is, you can assign a `list` or `numpy.array` to the values of your `Series`/`DataFrame`. For example, imagine you want to draw 1000 random samples of a binomial distribution with p=0.5:

```
p=0.5
my_data = pd.Series(np.random.binomial(1, p, input_length))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to N.P.'s answer. You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_df(df_len):

    values = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.1, size=df_len)
    return pd.DataFrame({'value': values})

df = generate_df(1000)
```

edit:

More complete function:

```
def generate_df(df_len, option, p_success=0.1):
    '''
    Generate a pandas DataFrame with one single field filled with
    1s and 0s in p_success proportion and length df_len.
    Input:
        - df_len: int, length of the 1st dimension of the DataFrame
        - option: string,  determines how will the sample be generated
            * random: according to a bernoully distribution with p=p_success
            * fixed: failures first, and fixed proportion of successes p_success
            * fixed_shuffled: fixed proportion of successes p_success, random order
        - p_success: proportion of successes among total
    Output:
        - df: pandas Dataframe
    '''

    if option == 'random':
        values = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=p_success, size=df_len)

    elif option in ('fixed_shuffled', 'fixed'):

        n_success = int(df_len*p_success)
        n_fail = df_len - n_success

        values = [0]*n_fail + [1]*n_success

        if option == 'fixed_shuffled':
            np.random.shuffle(values)

    else:
        raise Exception('Unknown option: {}'.format(option))

    df = pd.DataFrame({'value': values})

    return df
```